# Can't learn Master Smithing from Eorlund Graymane?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The master level trainer for Smithing will not allow me to train from him anymore, and I was wondering if this is a bug or if it's because I have a higher Smithing level than him or something?

Comment: I'm assuming you "spammed" him for training levels recently? If so, you'll have to wait a while, then come back and try again.

Comment: @Ben no i havent i did it prob last week but i went back today and he didnt allow me to get more levels

Comment: "Last week" in-game? You need to let time pass in-game, though I'm not sure how long.

Comment: @Ben well i did play for the whole week and it was a week irl

Comment: Ok no worries. Just wanted to clarify that

Comment: @Ben so do you know the problem or is my game just bugged

Comment: Personally, I can't say I know the answer to either.

Comment: @Ben well i guess im gonna have to farm levels by making things

Comment: How high is your smithing level?

Comment: @Vahx my smithing level is 99

Comment: An easy way to get smithing up is collect a large amount of leather and make leather bracers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No trainers can get you to level 100. See [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Trainer_%28Skyrim%29). Quote: "Unlike Oblivion, there are no means to be trained all the way to level 100 in a skill." Other wiki sites agree, [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim/Trainers) and [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Trainers).

90 is the maximum level you can get trained to by a Master trainer. After that, you have to do it yourself, by spamming weapons and/or armor in this case.

Comment: weapons, armor, and/or *jewelry*... or arrows? XP for arrows?